# How to execute AJAX spinner after success?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form which sometimes loads:

a) a new page or

b) an js action

I manage the spinner with done -> spinner stops and for the b), it's fine and works correctly, but not for a), because there's a period of time between ajax done and the new page shows where the spinner dissapears.

I can do an infinite loader, but if the user goes history back then the spinner will still be there plus i don't like it.

How can I manage the spinner to show till the user is still on the website and then 1 milisecond before quiting the page, restore everything?

I'm using js and jquery.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "loginposturl",
    data: data,
    method: 'POST',
}).done(function(data) {
    if(data.redirect){
        window.location.href = data.redirect;
    }else{
        $('#spinner').fadeOut();
    }
 }).always(function(data) {
    $('#spinner').fadeIn();
})
```

Comment: Please provide some source code.

Comment: question edited :)

Comment: I'm still not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve due to your choice of wording, however, I'm gonna take a shot in the dark here... But I'm assuming you're trying to continue to show the loader until the user has left the website?

Comment: yes, sorry if it's confusing, but you are right. I want to continue the loader till the user has left the website + if the user goes history back the loader will disappear so he can do the submit again.

Comment: Why not use something simple like ```sessionStorage``` then?

Comment: Try to add async: false to ajax settings

Comment: There's no need to try to make the ajax request synchronous, that alone wouldn't change much. You could just use ```sessionStorage```, then check for some flag within ```sessionStorage``` to see whether or not to show the spinner/loader? - Simple.

Comment: @JO3-W3B-D3Vhmm I'll investigate sessionStorage. Thx for that, I was thinking there was going to be some easyhack restore form on load or setTime delay or detetect window leaving to restore the form